# Please look Info on for statement in django

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop

I'm having some trouble joining or correctly formatting my template... I'm new and have taught myself alot so far, but I'm having trouble with queries and for statements.

What I have so far is:

Output

```
June 13, 2016 June 14, 2016
Item    Amount  Amount
Cars    10800.00
Tires   156400.00
10200.00
156001.00
About
```

What I want is to get the "second" output under the next amount column. Am I not making the correct queries?

template/Index

```
<body>

    {% if data %}
    {% if date %}
    {{ date.date }}
    {% endif %}
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>List Item</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            {% for firstdata in data %}
            <td>{{ firstdata.item }}</td>
            <td>{{ firstdata.amount }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for firstdata in data1 %}
            <td>{{ firstdata.amount }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <strong>There are no categories present.</strong>
    {% endif %}
    </table>

    <a href="/rango/about/">About</a>
</body>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):

context_dict = {}
statement = "Sales"
try:
    now = datetime.date.today()
    recentdate = StatementData.objects.order_by('date').distinct('date').filter(date__lte=now).reverse()[0]
    context_dict['date'] = recentdate
    first_statement = StatementData.objects.order_by('-id').filter(date=recentdate.date).values('item', 'amount')
    context_dict['data'] = first_statement

    now = datetime.date.today()
    recentdate1 = StatementData.objects.order_by('date').distinct('date').filter(cik=cik, date__lte=now).reverse()[1]
    #context_dict['date1'] = recentdate1
    second_statement = StatementData.objects.order_by('-id').filter(date=recentdate1.date).values('amount')
    #second_statement = StatementData.objects.order_by('-id').filter(date=recentdate1.date).values('id')
    context_dict['data1'] = second_statement

    #two_dates = first_statement | second_statement
    #context_dict['data1'] = two_dates

except StatementData.DoesNotExist:
    # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
    # Don't do anything - the template displays the "no category" message for us.
    pass

# Go render the response and return it to the client.
return render(request, 'profit/index.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: If the information in `data` and `data1` belongs together, it would make sense to pass it as one item instead of separate items.

Comment: How would I do that? How can I get {item: foo}, {amount: bar}, {amount: bat} When the second column of amounts is taken from a query filtered by a specific date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three solutions:

1) Manipulate the **front-end**, by making the second "*Amount*" column as another **separate table** outside the original table and then making the *display* property of both the tables as "**inline-block**".
Hence aligning them **side-by-side**.
Though the above is **not a good method to follow** in general

2) Add **another field** to your *StatementData model* say "Amount2" as commented by John Gordon. That way you'll have both Amount and Amount2 in 'data' and hence can simply write:

```
    {% for firstdata in data %}
        <td>{{ firstdata.item }}</td>
        <td>{{ firstdata.amount }}</td>
        <td>{{ firstdata.amount2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

But I get your problem that these are **two different amounts of the same item** on two different dates. So technically you can't have two fields for Amount in your model.

3) Technically this is the **ideal solution to your problem**, which is in a way what John Gordan was trying to say., that pass the whole as ONE object.

You need to define a class in your views say "Angell" and define three variables in it say "obj" , "amount1", "amount2"
Now you need to make a list of objects of class Angell which you can access in your HTML.
Following is the code to implement the same:

```
  class Angell:

       def __init__(self, obj, amount1, amount2):
           self.obj = obj
           self.amount1 = amount1
           self.amount2 = amount2


  def index(request):

      context_dict = {}
      statement = "Sales"
      try:
          now = datetime.date.today()
          recentdate = StatementData.objects.order_by('date').distinct('date').filter(date__lte=now).reverse()[0]
          context_dict['date'] = recentdate
          first_statement = StatementData.objects.order_by('-id').filter(date=recentdate.date).values('item', 'amount')
          #context_dict['data'] = first_statement

          now = datetime.date.today()
          recentdate1 = StatementData.objects.order_by('date').distinct('date').filter(cik=cik, date__lte=now).reverse()[1]
          #context_dict['date1'] = recentdate1
          second_statement = StatementData.objects.order_by('-id').filter(date=recentdate1.date).values('amount')
          #second_statement = StatementData.objects.order_by('-id').filter(date=recentdate1.date).values('id')
          #context_dict['data1'] = second_statement

          #two_dates = first_statement | second_statement
          #context_dict['data1'] = two_dates

          n = len(first_statement) #this should be equal to length of second_statement

          i = 0
          some_list = []

          while i < n:
              itm = first_statement[i].item
              amt1 = first_statement[i].amount
              amt2 = second_statement[i].amount

              Harp = Angell(itm, amt1, amt2)
              some_list.append(Harp)

              i += 1

          context_dict[data] = some_list


      except StatementData.DoesNotExist:
          # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
          # Don't do anything - the template displays the "no category" message for us.
          pass

      # Go render the response and return it to the client.
      return render(request, 'profit/index.html', context_dict)
```

And now your HTML looks like this:

```
    {% for firstdata in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ firstdata.obj }}</td>
            <td>{{ firstdata.amount1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ firstdata.amount2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: By God you are a GENIUS!! Thank you!!